# How to set Bootstrap `$enable-rounded: false;` in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, blazor, .net-5

How to set [Bootstrap `$enable-rounded: false;`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/) in Blazor WebAssembly?

I tried changing the `app.css` to `app.scss` and then compiled it using [`WebCompiler`](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler) but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work". Aren't the css files beeing created or are the created files ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to change these variables in the `_variables.scss` file as it says in the "Global options" heading.

Basically download the source for bootstrap, change the variable, recompile scss to css. More details in this section: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/#sass-options